# Boundaries or limitations when camera is open

Tags: javascript, java, python, android, flutter

I want to build an app where people have to take pictures of them selves. They have to be inside a rectangle which is drawn on their camera. I want to know how draw that rectangle when camera is open.
I've seen some apps where they ask you to put your face inside a circle.
The idea is to put some limitations or boundaries when camera is open.

Answer (score 0):

there are two plugins imagepicker and Camera

but imagepicker can't be customize. so your choice now is the Camera plugin it can be customize but you will start with blank camera without any button or widget. you must do it yourself.

camera plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/camera

camera demo: https://github.com/flutter-devs/flutter_camera_demo